# React Native AndroidManifest android:exported problem

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, targetsdkversion

When I upgrade targetSdkVersion to 12, I got AndroidManifest.xml Error
"*Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.*"
So I added android:exported. but same error.
Please see my AndroidManifest file and tell me where is error...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.andrei.gototu">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
      android:name="com.andrei.gototu.MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name="com.andrei.gototu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.kakao.sdk.auth.AuthCodeHandlerActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

          <!-- Redirect URI: "kakao{NATIVE_APP_KEY}://oauth“ -->
            <data android:host="oauth" android:scheme="kakao837edjj38e8djj3j4j4je43" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false"/>
      <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@android:color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions"/>
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher"/>
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
              <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

      <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the **android:exported="false"** in ***All activites, services and receivers***.

```
      <activity
        android:name="com.kakao.sdk.auth.AuthCodeHandlerActivity"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

          <!-- Redirect URI: "kakao{NATIVE_APP_KEY}://oauth“ -->
            <data android:host="oauth" android:scheme="kakao837edjj38e8djj3j4j4je43" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>


      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" android:exported="false"/>
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" android:exported="false"/>
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
              <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
  <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Comment: I got same error.

Comment: Please add `android:exported="true"` to all activities, services and receivers in the AndroidManifest.xml file.